# What standards are available for SOA authentication?

Tags: json, rest, soa, restful-authentication

Suppose I am in the following situation: I've an application that must access a remote service server offering a simple JSON RestFul API. I don't want to open this to everyone, but only to a certain number of hosts. Preferably, I'd like this to be token based (no sessions). I can think of many ways of implementing this, but I'd like to know if there is an open and widely adopted standard, so I can offer my services to third parties with ease and possibly no integration customization.

I googled a bit and I've found the OAuth protocol, but that seems more suited for social networks and website users. Or maybe I am wrong. What I need is something for internal service to use across an organization and possibly to offer to third parties.

Do you know of any?

Answer (score 0):

Since your are building a REST API that could possibly be offered to the outside but also you want to be used inside your organization, I would definitely go with [OAuth (2)](http://oauth.net/2/).

It's widely adopted and it's not used only for social networks and sites in general, it's also used in the enterprise, check this articles:

- [From Layer7](http://es.slideshare.net/rnewton/a-practical-guide-to-api-security-and-o-auth-for-the-enterprise)
- [From Intel](http://blogs.intel.com/application-security/2012/05/11/enterprise-apis-and-oauth-have-it-all/)

Of course that this is only related to your question, in other scenarios with more constraints regarding security maybe someone could recommend using SOAP services with WS-Security.